Does the Safe Harbor mean I only have to pay 100% of my total tax from last year until filing my tax return?
Say I made $100,000 in 2023 (under the $150,000 limit for the 110% rate). Assume over the course of 2024, I get a small raise and make a bunch of money selling stocks. Say I make $95,000 in capital gains, plus $105,000 in salary (total is $200,000, more than the $150,000 limit). My employer withholds for the $105,000 in salary, withholding slightly more than my total tax of 2023 (line 24 of my 2023 Form 1040). Assume I have not made any estimated tax payments. In both 2023 and 2024, I was employed full-time for the entire 12 months. Do I need to pay any additional taxes prior to April to avoid penalty?

Sounds to me like you'd be fine, but I'm not a financial professional. Make sure you're ready for the large lump-sum you'll owe, and remember that your safe-harbor next year will be based on 110% of the taxes on the whole $200k.

I have done this several times.
One occasion was when I sold a rental property. I knew I was going to owe money, so I just made sure that my withholding met the 100% safe harbor.
from IRS pub 505 for 2024

Higher Income Taxpayers
If your AGI for 2023 was more than $150,000 ($75,000 if your filing
status for 2024 is married filing a separate return), substitute 110%
for 100% in (2b) under General Rule, earlier.
For 2023, AGI is the amount shown on Form 1040 or 1040-SR, line 11.
Note.
This rule does not apply to farmers and fishers.

So the decision point for 100% or 110% is from last years tax return.
This safe harbor avoids the penalty for under-withholding and the need for making estimated payments.
If you are concerned you will miss the safe harbor, which can happen if the W-4 doesn't change, but some of your payroll deductions for insurance, and 401(k) do change; you can modify the W-4 to have extra money withheld. Hitting 100.5% is much better than 99.5%.
Looking ahead. Keep in mind based on your numbers you will probably need to hit 110% of your total 2024 taxes when you file the next time in April 2026.  Be prepared to have to adjust your withholding during 2025 to be able to make the safe harbor.
Also don't forget state taxes.

"Keep in mind based on your numbers you will probably need to hit 110% of your total taxes for 2024" -> Do you mean for 2025, I'll need 110% of my 2024 numbers? Just want to make sure I'm understanding right.

expanded the paragraph to mean the following year.

See the IRS Publication 505 and the IRC Sec. 6654. Generally if your total taxable income in 2023 is below 150K then your safe harbor is 90% of the tax due or 100% of the prior year tax, whatever is lower. So if your W2 withholding is enough to meet that threshold then you're not going to have penalties assessed if the remainder is paid by April 15th the following year. But be prepared for a large balloon payment with your tax return/extension filing.
